# Ttk background image

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

Is there any way to import an image into python using PIL and set it as the background for a ttk mainframe that spans the entirety of a Tkinter root window? As of now I have only seen ways to do this is a Tkinter root. Also is there any way to make ttk self adjust the size of the image so that even if it's small it covers the entire screen?

So to sum up I want an image to cover the entire ttk mainframe box without messing with me putting anything else in the ttk frame.

for example
if the pic covered the entire window, a command,

```
ttk.Button(root, text="Hello").grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,S,W,E))
```

would still insert a button in the mainframe. Thanks :)

Comment: What's the point of using a ttk frame for this, if you're going to cover it up? Just create a label with an image, and have it fill the window.

Comment: I'm not using the ttk frame JUST for the background... I'm going to be running my interface on that.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set an image background to a `ttk` frame, they don't accept image options. So you could make a `ttk` frame and put a label or something inside it and then have it span the frame adapting the below example.

Here's a small example demonstrating what you want. We load an image with pil, notice the image linked will be smaller (I hope) than your screensize.

So, we set the geometry of the root window to be the entire screen the image is less than this so we resize it to cover the entire width. You can override the max and min height and then set it according to this. Just a sample value. We then place the bg label and grid widgets on top of it. The label has a lower stacking order than the other widgets you will place with grid so they appear on top. Alternatively you could use a canvas, or another widget. With a canvas you'll have to use `create_window` to place widgets in the canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
width, height = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
#print(root.winfo_screenheight(), root.winfo_screenwidth())
root.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
#URL FOR BACKGROUND
#https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwiVroCiyZHMAhXKeT4KHQHpDVAQjBwIBA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwallpaperswide.com%2Fdownload%2Fblack_background_metal_hole_very_small-wallpaper-800x480.jpg&psig=AFQjCNEjZ7GDbjG9sFie-yXW3fP85_p0VQ&ust=1460840934258935
image = Image.open("background.jpg")
if image.size != (width, height):
    image = image.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    #print("DONE RESIZING")
    # image.save("background.jpg")
#print(image.size)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
bg_label = tk.Label(root, image = image)
bg_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
bg_label.image = image
your_button = ttk.Button(root, text='This is a button')
your_button.grid()
root.mainloop()
```